# htaccess file how to redirect all request to a subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

Due to uncontrollable factors, I cannot set the root path for my webapp, It was fixed to `/fixed/root/path/my_webapp`.

And I can't do any change on server. here is my foler struct

```
.
├── app/
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── .env
├── git_usage.md
├── phpunit.xml.dist
├── public/
├── readme.md
├── spark
├── vendor/
```

The only thing I can control is to edit a `.htaccess` file.

**What I want to achieve**

All request should be redirect to `public` folder.
The finnally. It will be similar to the `root` setting in Nginx

If I access `http://example.com.com/index.js` it will access `my_webapp/public/index.js`.
If I access `http://example.com.com/.env` it will not access `my_webapp/.env`. It should access `my_webapp/public/.env` and the file not exist, then It will try to access `my_webapp/public/index.php?/.env`(It means If file donesn't exist, It will be process by index.php).

here is my `.htaccess` in my root folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*?$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

I am useing the CI4 fromework of PHP. So there is already have a `.htaccess` under the `public` folder.

`public/.htaccess`:

```
# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    # RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

    # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

# Disable server signature start
    ServerSignature Off
# Disable server signature end
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be your root .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule .* public/$0 [L]
```

And something like this as your **last rule** in `public/.htaccess`:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# other rules here ...

# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
# such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
# request to the front controller, index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .+ index.php/$0 [L]
```

Comment: @ anubhava Server return me the 500 Error. I'm not sure if it's the server doing a special check

Comment: I'm try to use this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public;   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php [L]`. It works with redicreting all request that didn't access `/public`. But this rule cannot rewrite static resource, something like `example.com/js/index.js`.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Apache webserver?

Comment: This works even if there is another .htaccess at the destination. In my case a WordPress installation migrated from another site